# Dust collection for Bosch sliding miter saw

Tags: dust-collection

I have a Bosch 4410 sliding miter saw. It has a small dust port that I've found to be woefully inadequate as the sole means of dust extraction. My shop also has a 5HP cyclone dust collection system that I'd like to put to use on the miter saw. I'd made up a 28" x 44" hood, of sorts, using a couple of window well covers that helped somewhat but takes up too much real estate in the shop. The sliding mechanism extends nearly 16" behind the dust port, putting the hood too far away from the blade and dust port to get the job done effectively. The current thought is to build a smaller hood that attaches near the rear handle behind the motor using a 6" flexible collection hose connected to the shop dust collector. I've seen some nice hoods folks have designed, but none for a saw with a long slide mechanism. Suggestions???  [image: Bosch 4410 Miter Saw]